# How do I convert parameter values into unicode in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, arguments, diacritics

This is just about my first day using Python, and I'm trying to remove any accents in a set of arguments that I have. I know how to convert a given string to unicode:

```
myfoo = u'àà'
```

But how do I convert the arguments of a function into unicode?
My attempt was to create a function that began as follows:

```
def newfunction(args):
    myunicode = u'args['arg1']'
    convertedarg1 = unicodedata.normalize('NFD', my_unicode).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

But of course, this "converts" the string `"args['arg1']"` instead of the actual value given to `arg1`. I would like to fix the first step such that if arg1=café, convertedarg1 = cafe.

I hope that makes some sense.

Comment: Why do you not use  up-to-date Python version?

Comment: I wish I could, but I'm bound to 2.7 by the computers at work :(

Comment: Is your text editor using UTF-8?  Do you have this at the beginning of the source file?  `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`?

Comment: Which OS? In Windows, try `sys.argv[1].decode('cp1250')` (Use your ACP instead of `1250`). ACP obtained from `REG QUERY "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage" -v ACP`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yes, it did! Ultimately, I needed to write
dummy1 = args['arg1']
dummy2 = unicode(dummy1, "utf-8")
convertedarg1 = unicodedata.normalize('NFD', dummy2).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
Thank you so much!